# Eval code won't work

Tags: php

I am trying to make my own template engine, (Don't ask why!)

And will try making:

```
{{@Form::input("name")}}
```

In my rendering system i'll make this eval code:

```
    preg_match_all('/\{\{\@(.*?)\}\}/is',$data,$output);

    $out="";

    foreach ( $output[1] as $variables):
        $find = '{{@' . $variables . '}}';

        $data = str_replace($find, eval($variables), $data);
    endforeach;
```

But i am getting this error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/psafari/public_html/slt/classes/template.class.php(43) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

It should run "Form::input('something')" as specificed in the template engine. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's in `$variables`? Can you post some sample input?

Comment: there's so many thing wrong with this code. please rethink your approach. 99/100 when you use eval it's a bad idea.

Comment: `eval`ed code needs to contain a statement, not an unclosed expression. For example `return call()+1;`

Comment: $variables contains Form::input("name")

Comment: Thanks post as answer Mario.

Comment: **I very strongly recommend NOT using eval for this**. There's nothing wrong with making a templating engine, but you should absolutely not be using `eval()`. It is as big a security risk as you can get. Using `eval()` allows your end user to put any arbitrary PHP code they like. There's nothing wrong with a template that contains markers for code to be run, but it should be restricted to what it can do. `eval()` is the wrong solution.

Comment: @Spudley Would your warning still apply if only trusted users were allowed (or expected) to write templates?

Comment: @RandomSeed: Yes it would still apply. Even if it's behind your primary security, it still leaves you wide open to secondary attack. A hacker that gets past the basic security for a site can snoop around the system and may be able to deface the pages if he wants. That's bad enough. But if he then finds he can run `eval()`, he can do a huge amount more damage. Make your primary security as good as possible, but work on the assumption that it could be broken; you need to be as secure as possible even if someone does get through. Using `eval()` at any point in your system defeats all of that.

Comment: @Spudley I must disagree.. eval() is not evil and exists for a reason. Of course you should *never* let user input get into an eval (never trust the users) but this is a very valid use-case where eval is appropriate, only developers are writing the templates. If the "hacker can deface your pages" then an eval changes nothing, he could simply change the content to what ever he wishes. The "anti eval" rants are like "grandmother sayings", everybody knows them but nobody knows where they came from.. and they're often very far from the truth. Eval is key in any dynamic language.

Comment: @smassey - Okay, it's a rant. Also, it comes across harsher than I intended as I ran out of space. I hold my ground though: I do not believe this is a good place to be using eval, and I do believe that security in depth is an important consideration. Yes, there are cases where eval is appropriate, and there are things that can only be achieved using it, but most instances where it's actually used are not so: this example is a case in point - it is perfectly possible to write a templating system that doesn't use eval, while still retaining the functionality he wants.

Comment: @Spudley agreed on your second point! I honestly don't see why anyone would write a template engine in a language that is itself essentially a template engine/language :P template inception

Answer (score 0):

Despite the already *uber*-relevant comments against building a new templating engine, I'd suggest breaking the string found. Taking your example of `{{@Form::input("name")}}`, you'd have {{@**CLASS_NAME**::**FUNCTION_NAME**(*params*)}}. So using regex you could break the found string (as you already do), create an instance of or reference the class detected, then call the method parsed using a dynamic call (and obviously fail/error if either is not found).

As for the parameters, you could avoid qualifiers (quotes in this case) and break on every comma, or use the qualifiers and parse it differently via regex again. Your call. For each parameter parsed and found, they'd be added to the function call. In order to avoid `eval`, and given the fact PHP does not support a random number of arguments (such as Python does with `args` and `kwargs`), having an array as the single parameter for the functions you'll use on the template files.

You could also have sort of an 'interface' function that accepts a certain number of parameters that then receives the function (or class + function names), counts the number of parameters it finds and finally relays the call to the actual underlying function based on the correct number of parameters found. Though the more you add the more obscure the processing becomes - assuming users of your templating engine will be able to define new template methods, it's a very bad idea to use this second route (as you'd have to support up to *N* parameters on these *interface* functions).